# BLE UART Command/Response/ACK cycles

Tags: android, bluetooth, rxandroidble

I'm converting a very complex write/read/write cycle written on the native BLE stack and am wondering if the following pattern is feasible for handling in RxAndroidBLE (code is Kotlin)

```
fun sendCommandList(connection: RxBleConnection, commands: Array<String>) {
    Observable.fromArray(commands)
        .flatMapIterable { it.asIterable() } // convert to individual commands
        .map { it.toByteArray() }
        .map {
            connection.writeCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID, it)
                .flatMap { bytes -> connection.readCharacteristic((RX_CHAR_UUID)) }
                .flatMap { bytes -> val ackNackBytes = processResponse(bytes); connection.writeCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID, ackNackBytes) }

        }
        .subscribeBy( onError = { }, onComplete = { }, onNext = { })
}
```

I'm just trying to work out the code before I get access to the hardware so can't test this at the moment and am wondering if it's feasible. I'm more worried about the read portion if the complete response might be not be within one readCharacteristic(). If not would having a long running read pumping into a buffer that can be handled one byte at a time and removing only those bytes that make up a valid response and reading from that instead.

Thoughts? This seems like a common usage pattern, but I've been unable to find anything like it as far as samples.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to pull the information from the peripheral (read characteristic) and not wait for pushes (notifications)?

Comment: I wanted to be more linear in processing the responses in certain cases, but pitched the whole idea and went with separate read and write queues in the long run.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "linear" — sequential? Feel free to show your final output as it may be beneficial to some developers.